# Как умножить число в теге на число полученное через json?

Tags: javascript, html, json

На странице к примеру есть такой код:

```
<span class="cur-btc">100</span> BTC
```

Число 100 мне нужно умножить на значение из json, умножить на обычное число и округлить до 3 знаков после запятых. Как сделать одной функцией?

Значение json я буду получать здесь:

```
https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Отличное ТЗ))) Вот так:

```js
const roundPlus = (x, n) => { //x - число, n - количество знаков 
  if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(n)) return false;
  var m = Math.pow(10, n);
  return Math.round(x * m) / m;
}


const f = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1",
    dataType: "html"
  }).done(response => {
    let prostoeChislo = 5; //простое число
    let inTag = Number($("span.cur-btc").html());
    let inResponse = Number(response);
    let result = roundPlus((inTag * inResponse * prostoeChislo), 3);
    console.log("(В теге: " + inTag + ")", "(В json: " + inResponse + ")", "(Простое число: " + prostoeChislo + ")");
    console.log("Результат перемножения и округления: " + result);
    $("span.cur-btc").html(result);
  });
}

f();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="cur-btc">100</span> BTC
```

Comment: А если надо поместить результат туда откуда взяли, то есть заменить число 100?
Спасибо за быстрый ответ)

Comment: Вместо `100` внутри `span`?

Comment: Да, заменить результатом

Comment: `html(value)`. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Почти, только этот скрипт работает только с одним тегом, а у меня их может быть несколько одинаковых.

Мне скинули немного иное решение, но без умножения на свое число:

(async function() {
 const response = await fetch("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=1");
 const value = await response.json();

 for(const element of document.querySelectorAll(".cur-btc")) {
  element.textContent = (Number(element.textContent) * value).toFixed(3);
 }
})();

Comment: Дальше уж сами, @Дмитрий. На вопрос я ответил. Галочку оставьте себе.

Comment: Спасибо за варианты, дальше действительно сам